# Figure referencing isn't working with PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, floats, cross-referencing

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            \addplot[domain=0:360]({cos(x)},{sin(x)});
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{This was generated with PGFPlots.}
    }
    \end{center}
    \label{fig-circle}
\end{figure}

See figure~\ref{fig-circle}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}{
    \includegraphics{header.png}
}
\end{center}
\caption{This was read from a PNG file.}
\label{fig-image}
\end{figure}

See also figure~\ref{fig-image}.

\end{document}
```

This compiles as follows:

[image]

Using the `article` documentclass also results in "See figure ??." being printed.

I'm 100% sure I've built figures with PGFPlots and referenced them in the text before. I have no idea what's wrong this time.

What's going on?

(For bonus points, why does my compiler result in an error if I remove the `titletoc` package and/or the `subfig` package? I'm pretty sure it doesn't need either of those to compile that MWE. I'm also pretty sure I've compiled things without those packages previously. I'm using TeXShop 4.68, if that makes any difference.)

Comment: `\caption` defines local macros like `\@currentlabel` which are used by `\label`.  Ending groups and environments lose all internal local definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question, but apparently you are having problems with the label reference 1. If so, placing `\label{fig-circle}` next to caption `\caption{This was generated with PGFPlots.}`, i.e. something like `\caption{This was generated with PGFPlots.}\label{fig-circle}`, may solve your problem. don't forget to compile twice.

Comment: @O'Neil Thank you for correcting my English, as you may notice English is not my native language. Apologies in advance, if it is bad, poor and broken, a thousand apologies :)

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was playing around with the placement of `\label{fig-circle}` and it seems placing it inside the `center` environment (i.e. two lines above its position in my MWE) does the trick. No idea why that's important.